# .Name refers to a property or field that is not from type

Tags: c#, linq, cassandra, linq-to-entities

This is the mapping function

```
 var mapData = new Map<RxHsLocationStateTbl>().TableName("test");
            mapData.Column(c => c.ContinentNameNormalized, cm => cm.WithName(nameof(RxHsLocationStateTbl.ContinentNameNormalized)));
           
            return mapData;
```

Is I map properties in this way then everything works fine

but if I try to make this process automated and try to map properties automatically then I am getting this error

```
public static Map<T> AutoMap<T>(List<string> exclude) where T : class
    {
        var tableName = typeof(T).Name.ToLower();
        var mapData = new Map<T>().TableName(tableName);
        foreach (var p in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (!exclude.Contains(p.Name))
            {
                mapData.Column( c=> c.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).Name, cm =>  cm.WithName(p.Name.ToLower()));
            }
        }
        return mapData;
    }

AutoMap<RxHsLocationCityTbl>(new List<string>());
```

> Error message : .The name refers to a property or field that is not from
> type

This is the inside of this column function

```
   /// <summary>Defines options for mapping the column specified.</summary>
    public Map<TPoco> Column<TProp>(
      Expression<Func<TPoco, TProp>> column,
      Action<ColumnMap> columnConfig)
    {
      if (column == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (column));
      if (columnConfig == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (columnConfig));
      MemberInfo propertyOrField = this.GetPropertyOrField<TProp>(column);
      ColumnMap columnMap;
      if (!this._columnMaps.TryGetValue(propertyOrField.Name, out columnMap))
      {
        Type memberInfoType = propertyOrField as PropertyInfo != (PropertyInfo) null ? ((PropertyInfo) propertyOrField).PropertyType : ((FieldInfo) propertyOrField).FieldType;
        columnMap = new ColumnMap(propertyOrField, memberInfoType, true);
        this._columnMaps[propertyOrField.Name] = columnMap;
      }
      columnConfig(columnMap);
      return this;
    }
```

I don't understand. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: noone have a solution ?

Comment: Make sure that your question includes a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Have you tried not specifying the column names? The driver will automatically map the columns by property name. That error is not a driver error I don't think, is there a stack exception to give us more info? It would help a lot if you could give us a minimal reproducible example.